# Number of Palindrome Substrings Program Failing to Run

Tags: c++, algorithm, palindrome

I have a homework assignment that asks us to use dynamic programming to count the number of possible palindrome substrings in a given string. My program, theoretically, should work, but when I run it, the run fails every time. I do not get any compiler errors. Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <stack>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
/*bool isPalindrome(string input){
    bool isPal = true;
    int j = (input.length() - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < (input.length()/2); i++){
        if(input[i] != input[j]){
            isPal = false;
        }
        j--;
    }
    return isPal;
}*/

bool isPalindrome(string input, bool array[5000][5000], int i, int j) {
    int a = i;
    int b = j;

    if(array[i][j])
        return true;

    while(input[a] == input[b]){
        array[a][b] = true;
        a++;
        b--;
        if((b - a) <= 2){
            break;
        }
    }
    return array[i][j];
}

int numPalindrome(string input) {
    bool array[5000][5000];
    for(int k = 0; k < 5000; k++)
        for(int n = 0; n < 5000; n++)
            array[k][n] = false;

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        for(int j = i; j <= input.length(); j++){
            if(isPalindrome(input, array, i, j)){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int count = numPalindrome("xabcba");
    cout << "Count: " << count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help find out why my code will not run? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Are all of those header files necessary?

Comment: You need boundary checking in your array usage.

Comment: Just a small sidenote, but this code is absolutely horrible in efficiency (~24MB of memory, for a simply palindrome check is a bit of an overkill). The error itself can be easily found by debugging (this code is'nt commented at all, so it's pretty difficult to answer the question anyways). and palindroms can be found a lot more efficient (i've answered a similar question somewhere else and comment a link here, as soon as i find it)

Comment: what's the failure you are getting?

Comment: I recommend passing the string by constant reference, so you don't waste execution time or space by passing a copy of the input string.

Comment: Also don't use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My instructor provided a template to start with that included all the headers. I just haven't taken the time to remove the ones I don't need. Can you expand on the boundary checking?

Comment: Boundary checking:  verifying that the indices you use with an array are within the size (capacity) of the array.  If I declare an array of 5, I have to make sure my index variable does not go past 4, since slots are zero based (starts at 0 not one).

Comment: @Pawan It seems to be a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

All palindromes in a string can be represented as a graph like this:

```
len
 4                    abba
                     /  | \
 3        aba       /   |  \       aca
         / | \     /    |   \     / | \
 2      /  |  \   /    bb    \   /  |  \   aa
       /   |   \ /    /  \    \ /   |   \ /  \
 1    a    b    a    b    b    a    c    a     a
```

This relation-ship can be used pretty easy to find all palindromes and reducing space-complexity to `O(n)`. And reducing the runtime-complexity by a great ammount, since we only need to search for all palindromes with length 2 and 3. So unless the input is worstcase ("aaaaaa...aaaaaa" for eg.), we can reduce the number of searched words by a great amount. The basic idea is to simply store the position of palindromes at an even or uneven position and search for palindromes that are two characters longer. Given a list of the positions of palindromes with length `n`, we can search for palindromes with length `n + 2` by simply checking if the character next to the previous palindrome on the left and right side are equal.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to implement this in code? I tried a brute force method that just checked each substring individually, but my professor said that was too inefficient. He talked through some pseudocode that I implemented in the file above. A friend of mine did the same thing in java, and it worked for him. We're supposed to use "dynamic programming" to complete this problem.